# Sending sms from twitter to mobile number

Tags: json, web-services, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am building web application that will send sms to users on their mobile numbers. 
I have been asked to use twitter sms service. After some googling, i come to know that i can send sms/tweet using twitter api to users that are my friend at twitter and they have set up their mobile number to receive tweets on their mobile number.

My questions is that can i send sms to any mobile number (not registered at twitter) using twitter api from my twitter account. Is there any work around?

Thanking you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use SMS follow, SMS follow is used to receive Twitter account updates without having to sign up or add your phone to a Twitter account.

[This](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170004) helped me.